# Do stand by servers also have check points when they flush the data from WAL logs?

Tags: postgresql, wal

I was curious to know how does end to end replication takes place, The primary replicates WAL to stand by servers, and then the data is committed to the disk, as part of checkpoints also in standby?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, checkpoints also happen while the database is in recovery, for example on a standby server. They are called *restartpoints*, but are pretty much the same thing. If you stop and restart the standby server (or a server doing archive recovery), it will continue recovering at the latest restartpoint.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/hot-standby.html#HOT-STANDBY-ADMIN):

> The checkpointer process and the background writer process are active during recovery. The checkpointer process will perform restartpoints (similar to checkpoints on the primary) and the background writer process will perform normal block cleaning activities. This can include updates of the hint bit information stored on the standby server. The `CHECKPOINT` command is accepted during recovery, though it performs a restartpoint rather than a new checkpoint.